# I am using msbiuild to call my itegrations tests using open cover. I want to append all the results into one XML file. Is this possible?

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, nunit, teamcity, opencover

I am using msbuild to call my integrations tests using open cover.  I want to append all the results into one XML file.  Is this possible?

Currently I run open cover against each individual dll we have.  This produces an xml file for each dll.  Is there a way of just having all the results appended into the one file when running from opencover?

I would like to get all the results appended into the default test results .xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-mergeoutput` [switch](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/wiki/Usage) that allows the output of one run to be loaded and the data updated into the next run.

Answer (score 0):

I used ReportGenerator to amalgamate all the OpenCover results and used the existing team city nunit reporter, to report on the nunit results generated.  This gives me two reports from all runs.  One with coverage and the second with just the nunit results.